# Specifying which iPhone OS to run on the device?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I have noticed in the iPhone Simulator an option in one of the menus to specify which OS to run the Simulator under. I'm wondering if something similar is possible for the device itself (of which I have only one), so I can test my app on the actual hardware under varying OS versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can load a specific version of the OS for testing (FYI, I have not tried this myself, so I do not know how long it takes, etc.). Plus, it probably wipes all the data.

[iPhone Development Guide: Restoring System Software](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices/devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW38)

> 4 . From the Software Version pop-up menu, choose the version of iPhone OS you want to place on the device.

If your one device is also your main phone, this might not be practical though.

Comment: yes you can always re-install another version of the os on the device but I dont think this is whats he has in mind.

Comment: I'm looking for any and all solutions at this point -- of course a solution that doesn't require me to reset my device is preferred, but so far it doesn't seem like an option.

Comment: there not any option but to get another device

Comment: i have an ipod touch just for that purpose but of course it lacks some of the functionality of the phone

Comment: It may not be a workable solution for having a single device (takes time, resets the device, etc.), but it IS possible to run different versions of the OS on a device.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible since the iphone cant run multiple versions of its os.  The simulator allows you to do this since it running a vm to simulate the os.