# Can I dual boot two iPhone OS's?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I'm a developer and don't want to commit to iOS4 yet as it's buggy, but a few of my clients will be early adopters. Can I use OpeniBoot (or something similar) to boot two legit OS's (preferably 3.1.3 and iOS 4)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer:
No.

Long answer:
No, because Apple put in checks for this after people did this with 1.1 and 2.0. They only want to be on the first partition, so you can't have two OS versions on different paritions. Theoretically, you could patch this out, and have two partitions, but it's going to be extremely difficult and probably cheaper to just buy a second device.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can use Xcode to re-imbue any version of the iPhone OS onto a device that supports it. The caveat is the contents of the device will be completely reset. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380379/specifying-which-iphone-os-to-run-on-the-device) for more information (specifically [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW2) from Apple).

As far as using tools like OpeniBoot, I'm not aware of a solution.

Comment: Thanks I have actually tried to use this before, but its really not viable as it takes AGES to reflash, (about 15 minutes or more) and therefore is not worth it for the amount of dev I do, looks like a 2nd handset is the way forward